# A new form in a main form

Tags: c#, winforms, call

in C# forms I need code to add a second form to my existing. this is what I've tried:

First form:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmMain fM = new frmMain();
        fM.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(MMForm);

    }
    private void MMForm(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        Keys KP; KP = (Keys)sender;
        if (KP == Keys.Escape) { frm2 fM2 = new frm2(); fM2.Show(); }

    }
}
```

And this is Second form:

```
public class frm2 : Form
{
    public frm2()
    {
        frm2 fM2 = new frm2();
        fM2.Height = 200; fM2.Width = 200;
        Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Form[] { fM2 });
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: forget all this for a moment. Even if I do it as suggested down there I get an error when I press the key.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Project 09.exe
Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Comment: you could set the Height and Width using this. if you want to set it for the current instance. I am little confused because of this new object of frm2 creation inside of the constructor.

Comment: What are you trying to do here, do you want to start frm2 on Escape key press on main form ?

Comment: A form is a toplevel window, it doesn't want to be a child control unless you use a bigger hammer.  A UserControl is a proper substitute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.private void MMForm(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    }
    private void MMForm(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
     {
        if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(((int)Keys.Escape)))
        {
            frm2 fM2 = new frm2(); fm2.Height=200; fm2.Width=200; fM2.Show(); 
        }
}

public class frm2 : Form 
{ 
    public frm2() 
    {  
        InitializeComponent();
    } 
}
```

Comment: treid, can not write

        InitializeComponent(); 

In second form

Comment: I had an extra comma in InitializeComponent() of second form, just removed it.

Comment: Nah, it s a bit different, look at comments on other answers

Comment: And if you have any other control on the main form, that the escape key will not work, As the focus will always in the other control and not on form. So escape even will fire on that control and not form. I have updated the code. Alternatively you can use mouse click event as well instead of key press.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmMain fM = new frmMain();
    fM.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(MMForm);

}
```

Replace with this:

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(MMForm);
}
```

Or you can just register to your own KeyPress via designer, directly to MMForm...

And also, it is unclear what you are trying to do here:

```
public frm2()
{
    frm2 fM2 = new frm2();
    fM2.Height = 200; fM2.Width = 200;
    Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Form[] { fM2 });
}
```

It should probably look more like this:

```
public frm2()
{
    InitializeComponents();
    this.Height = 200;
    this.Width = 200;
}
```

Even if you don't want to InitializeComponents, you should edit your own (this) properties, not a new frm2 properties.
You've had the same problem in frmMain_Load, when you created a new frmMain, and subscribed to it's KeyPress, when really you should've subscribed to your own KeyPress.

Also, you can shorten your MMForm just to beautify, like so:

```
private void MMForm(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Keys)sender == Keys.Escape)
    {
        new frm2().Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: both, I mean there is no problem in executing the program it's just that it doesnt do anything.

Comment: It should open a new frm2 whenever you press Escape in your main form. Read my comment to your comment at the other guy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. frm2 does not use InitializeComponent() command. so add it to your code.
2. secondly you try to add frm2 object to itself, so it will not work.

you should use the code belove for your exiting form (and set please its weight from properties, if you will not resize the form.

```
public class frm2 : Form 
{ 
    public frm2() 
    {  
        InitializeComponent(); ,
        this.Width = 200; this.Height = 200; 
    } 
}
```

And after a special key if you want to display frm2 :

```
frm2 secondFrom = new frm2();
frm2.Show(); // frm2.ShowDialog(); works too but they are working differently.
```

Comment: hmmm. the problem is both form1 and 2 are on the same page of the code, I am trying to create another form within first one.

Comment: You should probably read about MDI (MDIChild and MDIParent). MDI is where the child form is actually a part of the parent form. The forms are completely separate in code, but the main form is defined to be MDIParent.

Comment: you should add your form from solution. right click on solution add new windows form. so designer.cs file and other neccessary parts will be ready for you.

Comment: I guess I hoped it could work this way but ok, I ll just do it like that then. thank you for help all

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to open frm2 when escape key is pressed on the main form do the following:

```
public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(MMForm);
    }
//You don't need to put anything in form load
    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

//This is fine
    private void MMForm(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        Keys KP; KP = (Keys)sender;
        if (KP == Keys.Escape) { frm2 fM2 = new frm2(); fM2.Show(); }
    }
```

In frm2 do:

```
public class frm2 : Form
{
    public frm2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Height = 200; this.Width = 200;
        Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Form[] { fM2 });
    }

}
```

Comment: I am actually trying to open a new form within the code of first one. didnt add second form to solution or anything

Comment: @AntonioTehSumtin, so you mean that frm2 is not in the solution ?? I don't think you will be able to do it this way, Why you are not adding it to the solution